# How is a binary tree represented in an adjacency list?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, adjacency-list

I was looking at an example of a binary tree in an adjacency list format and I couldn't figure out what the binary tree equivalent looks like. There was a representation but the ordering didn't make sense e.g. left/right/parent.

Searching didn't yield any results of how to figure out a binary tree from an adjacency list.

Given some adjacency list like the following where each index `i` is the vertex and the unordered lists are the vertex i neighbors `[[5,7,9], [2], [1,5,6]]` (not sure if this is a binary tree, just wrote it to my best guess) how do you construct a binary tree?

Comment: The first thing is to make sure you're clear what the syntax means, which you may have to verify with whoever gave it to you.  My guess is that your example means there are edges from node 1 to nodes 5, 7, 9; from node 2 to itself, and from node 3 to nodes 1,5,6.  You should be able to draw a picture of this graph.  A binary tree is just a special kind of graph, so you can represent it by an adjacency list just like any other graph.

Comment: hmm, ok. Thanks Nate! I'll try and take another look.